# Assistance Converting NSInvocation Code to ARC Compatible (Already Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, nsinvocation

I found some really great code from Matt Gallagher for use with making Undo work with NSInvocation.  Though now Management wants us to use ARC for all of our code and we are now converting all of our code to ARC. This Last Piece is all that is left.  Matt, does not have the time to do the Conversion, so I was hoping that I could get some help here.

Any assistance would be appreciated!

Thank you!

**NSInvocation(ForwardedConstruction).h**

```
        //
        //  NSInvocation(ForwardedConstruction).h
        //
        //  Created by Matt Gallagher on 19/03/07.
        //  Copyright 2007 Matt Gallagher. All rights reserved.
        //
        //  Permission is given to use this source code file without charge in any
        //  project, commercial or otherwise, entirely at your risk, with the condition
        //  that any redistribution (in part or whole) of source code must retain
        //  this copyright and permission notice. Attribution in compiled projects is
        //  appreciated but not required.
        //


        @interface NSInvocation (ForwardedConstruction)

        + (id)invocationWithTarget:(id)target
            invocationOut:(NSInvocation **)invocationOut;
        + (id)retainedInvocationWithTarget:(id)target
            invocationOut:(NSInvocation **)invocationOut;

        @end
```

**NSInvocation(ForwardedConstuction).m**

```
        //
        //  NSInvocation(ForwardedConstuction).m
        //
        //  Created by Matt Gallagher on 19/03/07.
        //  Copyright 2007 Matt Gallagher. All rights reserved.
        //
        //  Permission is given to use this source code file without charge in any
        //  project, commercial or otherwise, entirely at your risk, with the condition
        //  that any redistribution (in part or whole) of source code must retain
        //  this copyright and permission notice. Attribution in compiled projects is
        //  appreciated but not required.
        //

    #import "NSInvocation(ForwardedConstruction).h"
    #import <objc/runtime.h>
    #import <objc/message.h>


        //
        // InvocationProxy is a private class for receiving invocations via the
        // forwarding mechanism and saving the received invocation to an external
        // invocation pointer.
        //
        // To avoid as many instance methods as possible, InvocationProxy is a base
        // class (not a subclass of NSObject) and does not implement the NSObject
        // protocol (and so is *not* a first-class object).
        //
    @interface InvocationProxy
    {
        Class isa;
        NSInvocation **invocation;
        id target;
        BOOL retainArguments;
        NSUInteger forwardingAddress;
    }

    /*+ (id)alloc;*/
    + (void)setValuesForInstance:(InvocationProxy *)instance
                          target:(id)target
           destinationInvocation:(NSInvocation **)destinationInvocation
                 retainArguments:(BOOL)retain;
    - (NSMethodSignature *)methodSignatureForSelector:(SEL)aSelector;
    - (void)forwardInvocation:(NSInvocation *)forwardedInvocation;

    @end

    #ifndef __OBJC_GC__

        //
        // DeallocatorHelper is a basic object which takes an id
        // and deallocates it when the DeallocatorHelper is deallocated.
        //
        // Not used in a garbage collected environment (which should deallocate the
        // id automatically).
        //
    @interface DeallocatorHelper : NSObject
    {
        id object;
    }

    - (id)initWithObject:(id)newObject;
    - (void)dealloc;

    @end

    @implementation DeallocatorHelper

        //
        // initWithObject
        //
        // Init method for objects which sets the id to be autoreleased.
        //
    - (id)initWithObject:(id)newObject
    {
        self = [super init];
        if (self != nil)
        {
            object = newObject;
        }
        return self;
    }

        //
        // dealloc
        //
        // Deallocates the id.
        //
    - (void)dealloc
    {
        NSDeallocateObject(object); 
        [super dealloc];
    }

    @end

    #endif

    @implementation InvocationProxy

        //
        // initialize
        //
        // This empty method is required because the runtime tries to invoke it when
        // the first message is sent to the Class. If it doesn't exist, the runtime
        // gets mad.
        //
    + (void)initialize
    {
    }


        //
        // alloc
        //
        // Allocator for the class. Also sets the 
        //
    + (id)alloc
    {
            //
            // Allocate the object using the default allocator.
            //
        InvocationProxy *newObject =
    #ifdef __OBJC_GC__
        objc_allocate_object(self, 0);
    #else
        NSAllocateObject(self, 0, nil);
    #endif
        return newObject;
    }


    - (id)init {  
        return self;  
    }

        //
        // setValuesForInstance:target:destinationInvocation:retainArguments:
        //
        // Method to set the attributes on the instance passed in. We use a class
        // method instead of an instance method to avoid extra instance methods on
        // the class.
        //
    + (void)setValuesForInstance:(InvocationProxy *)instance
                          target:(id)destinationTarget
           destinationInvocation:(NSInvocation **)destinationInvocation
                 retainArguments:(BOOL)retain;
    {
        instance->target = destinationTarget;
        instance->invocation = destinationInvocation;
        instance->retainArguments = retain;
    }

        //
        // methodSignatureForSelector:
        //
        // Invoked by the runtime whenever a message is sent for a method that doesn't
        // exist.
        //
    - (NSMethodSignature *)methodSignatureForSelector:(SEL)aSelector
    {
            //
            // This method should be invoked once before attributes are set (as an
            // "init" invocation).
            //
        if (target == nil)
        {
                //
                // If the invocation is something other than "init", complain using
                // NSObject's standard doesNotRecognizeSelector:
                //
            if (aSelector != @selector(init))
            {
                SEL failSEL = @selector(doesNotRecognizeSelector:);
                Method failMethod =
                class_getInstanceMethod([NSObject class], failSEL);
                IMP failImp = method_getImplementation(failMethod);
                failImp(self, failSEL, aSelector);
            }

                //
                // Otherwise, we use the forwarded "init" to preserve the return
                // address of the forwarding code (which we can use later to determine
                // if this is a forwarded or direct invocation).
                //
            forwardingAddress = (NSUInteger)__builtin_return_address(0);

                //
                // Return the NSMethodSignature from NSObject's init method (just
                // so we have something to return).
                //
            return [NSObject instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:aSelector];
        }

            //
            // On subsequent invocations, check if we are a forwarded invocation or
            // a direct invocation.
            //
        NSUInteger returnAddress = (NSUInteger)__builtin_return_address(0);
        if (returnAddress != forwardingAddress)
        {
                //
                // Handle the case where methodSignatureForSelector: is the message sent
                // directly to the proxy.
                //
                // There is a chance that we have guessed wrong (i.e. if this is sent
                // from __forward__ but from a different code branch) but that won't
                // cause a fatal problem, just a redundant autoreleased NSInvocation
                // that will get safely autoreleased and ignored.
                //
                // Create an NSInvocation for methodSignatureForSelector: 
                //
            NSMethodSignature *signature =
            [target methodSignatureForSelector:_cmd];
            *invocation =
            [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:signature];
            [*invocation setTarget:target];
            [*invocation setSelector:_cmd];
            [*invocation setArgument:&aSelector atIndex:2];
            if (retainArguments)
            {
                [*invocation retainArguments];
            }

                //
                // Deliberately fall through and still return the target's
                // methodSignatureForSelector: result (in case we guessed wrong).
                //
        }

            //
            // This is the "normal" case: after initialization, we have been correctly
            // invoked from the forwarding code. Return the target's
            // methodSignatureForSelector: for the given selector.
            //
        NSMethodSignature *signature =
        [target methodSignatureForSelector:aSelector];

        NSAssert3(signature != nil,
                  @"NSInvocation(ForwardedConstruction) error: object 0x%@ of class '%@' does not implement %s",
                  target, [target className], sel_getName(aSelector));

        return signature;
    }

        //
        // forwardInvocation:
        //
        // This method is invoked by message forwarding.
        //
    - (void)forwardInvocation:(NSInvocation *)forwardedInvocation
    {
            //
            // This method will be invoked once on initialization (before target is set).
            // Do nothing.
            //
        if (target == nil)
        {
                //
                // This branch will be followed when "init" is invoked on the newly
                // allocated object. Since "init" returns "self" we need to set that
                // on the forwardedInvocation.
                //
            [forwardedInvocation setReturnValue:&self];
            return;
        }

            //
            // Check if the target of the forwardedInvocation is equal to self. If
            // it is, then this is a genuine forwardedInvocation. If it isn't, then
            // forwardInvocation: was directly the message sent to this proxy.
            //
        if ([forwardedInvocation target] == self)
        {
            [forwardedInvocation setTarget:target];
            *invocation = forwardedInvocation;
            if (retainArguments)
            {
                [*invocation retainArguments];
            }
            return;
        }

            //
            // Handle the case where forwardedInvocation is the message sent directly
            // to the proxy. We create an NSInvocation representing a forwardInvocation:
            // sent to the target instead.
            //
        NSMethodSignature *signature =
        [target methodSignatureForSelector:_cmd];
        *invocation =
        [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:signature];
        [*invocation setTarget:target];
        [*invocation setSelector:_cmd];
        [*invocation setArgument:&forwardedInvocation atIndex:2];
        if (retainArguments)
        {
            [*invocation retainArguments];
        }
    }

    @end

    @implementation NSInvocation (ForwardedConstruction)

        //
        // invocationWithTarget:invocationOut:
        //
        // Basic constructor for NSIncoation using forwarded construction.
        //
    + (id)invocationWithTarget:(id)target
                 invocationOut:(NSInvocation **)invocationOut
    {
            //
            // Check that invocationOut isn't nil.
            //
        NSAssert2(target != nil && invocationOut != nil,
                  @"%@ method %s requires target that isn't nil and a valid NSInvocation** for the second parameter",
                  [self className], sel_getName(_cmd));

            //
            // Alloc and init the proxy
            //
        InvocationProxy *invocationProxy = [[InvocationProxy alloc] init];

            //
            // Set the instance attributes on the proxy
            //
        [InvocationProxy
         setValuesForInstance:invocationProxy
         target:target
         destinationInvocation:invocationOut
         retainArguments:NO];

            //
            // Create the DeallocatorHelper if needed
            //
    #ifndef __OBJC_GC__
            [[[DeallocatorHelper alloc]
                    initWithObject:invocationProxy]
                autorelease];
    #endif

        return invocationProxy;
    }

        //
        // retainedInvocationWithTarget:invocationOut:
        //
        // Same as above but sends retainArguments to the NSInvocation created.
        //
    + (id)retainedInvocationWithTarget:(id)target
                         invocationOut:(NSInvocation **)invocationOut
    {
            //
            // Check that invocationOut isn't nil.
            //
        NSAssert2(target != nil && invocationOut != nil,
                  @"%@ method %s requires target that isn't nil and a valid NSInvocation** for the second parameter",
                  [self className], sel_getName(_cmd));

            //
            // Alloc and init the proxy
            //
        InvocationProxy *invocationProxy = [[InvocationProxy alloc] init];

            //
            // Set the instance attributes on the proxy
            //
        [InvocationProxy
         setValuesForInstance:invocationProxy
         target:target
         destinationInvocation:invocationOut
         retainArguments:YES];

            //
            // Create the DeallocatorHelper if needed
            //
    #ifndef __OBJC_GC__
        [[[DeallocatorHelper alloc]
          initWithObject:invocationProxy]
         autorelease];
    #endif

        return invocationProxy;
    }

    @end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid this altogether:

Select this file at Target > Build Phases > Compile Sources in Xcode.

PRESS ENTER.

Type -fno-objc-arc.

Press Done.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Matt you should add the "-fno-objc-arc" flag when compiling the file, but it is not enough. You need to do two things to make sure your invocation gets called as expected.

First always add "__autoreleasing" in the declaration of the variable; you should have something like:

```
NSInvocation *__autoreleasing invocation;
[[NSInvocation retainedInvocationWithTarget:self invocationOut:&invocation] myMethod];
```

If you fail to do this ARC will set "invocation" to nil before you have time to use it.

Then you need to modify forwardInvocation: in the NSInvocation override. This is required because ARC will send "retain" and "release" to the proxy object and you do not want these to interfere (this means that you will not be able to use the code to create invocations for "retain" and "release" messages, but you most probably weren't).

```
- (void)forwardInvocation:(NSInvocation *)forwardedInvocation
{
    //
    // This method will be invoked once on initialization (before target is set).
    // Do nothing.
    //
    if (target == nil)
    {
        //
        // This branch will be followed when "init" is invoked on the newly
        // allocated object. Since "init" returns "self" we need to set that
        // on the forwardedInvocation.
        //
        [forwardedInvocation setReturnValue:&self];
        return;
    }
    if (forwardedInvocation.selector == @selector(retain))
    {
        // This branch will be followed when "retain" is invoked on the newly
        // allocated object. ARC will call retain before the selector we want
        // the signature of is invoked, so we need to return "self" to track
        // the next forward invocation.
        [forwardedInvocation setReturnValue:&self];
        return;
    }
    if (forwardedInvocation.selector == @selector(release))
    {
        // This branch will be followed when "release" is invoked on the newly
        // allocated object. ARC will call release after the selector we want
        // the signature of is invoked.
        return;
    }

    //
    // Check if the target of the forwardedInvocation is equal to self. If
    // it is, then this is a genuine forwardedInvocation. If it isn't, then
    // forwardInvocation: was directly the message sent to this proxy.
    //
    if ([forwardedInvocation target] == self)
    {
        [forwardedInvocation setTarget:target];
        *invocation = forwardedInvocation;
        if (retainArguments)
        {
            [*invocation retainArguments];
            //[forwardedInvocation retainArguments]; // added
        }
        // [forwardedInvocation setReturnValue:forwardedInvocation]; // added
        return;
    }

    //
    // Handle the case where forwardedInvocation is the message sent directly
    // to the proxy. We create an NSInvocation representing a forwardInvocation:
    // sent to the target instead.
    //
    NSMethodSignature *signature =
    [target methodSignatureForSelector:_cmd];
    *invocation =
    [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:signature];
    [*invocation setTarget:target];
    [*invocation setSelector:_cmd];
    [*invocation setArgument:&forwardedInvocation atIndex:2];
    if (retainArguments)
    {
        [*invocation retainArguments];
    }
}
```